# $\int\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu\to\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu\Leftrightarrow\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu\to 0$

Tags: proof-verification, measure-theory

> > Consider a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ and let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions out of
> >     $$
> > \mathfrak{L}_{\mu}^1=\left\{f\colon (\Omega,\mathfrak{A})\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\overline{\mathcal{B}}): f\text{ measurable }, \int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\infty.\right\}
> > $$
> >     with $f_n\to f$ almost surely, $f\in\mathfrak{L}_{\mu}^1$. Show that
> >     $$
> > \int\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu\to\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu\Leftrightarrow\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu\to 0.
> > $$

Good evening!

Here is my recent proof.

**Proof**

"$\Rightarrow$": Consider the functions
$$
\tilde{f_n}:=\lvert f_n\rvert+\lvert f\rvert-\lvert f_n-f\rvert
$$
which are non-negative (because $\lvert f_n-f\rvert\leq\lvert f_n\rvert+\lvert f\rvert$) and measurable (because the functions $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable). Moreover it is $\tilde{f_n}\to 2\lvert f\rvert$ almost surely, because 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lvert f_n\rvert+\lvert f\rvert-\vert f_n-f\rvert)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lvert f_n\rvert)+\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lvert f\rvert)-\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lvert f_n-f\rvert)=\lvert f\rvert+\lvert f\rvert-0.
$$
Now I apply Fatou's lemma:
\begin{align}
2\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu&=\int\underbrace{\liminf_{n\to\infty}\tilde{f_n}}_{=\lim_{n\to\infty}\tilde{f_n}}\, d\mu\\&\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int\tilde{f_n}\, d\mu\\&=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int(\lvert f_n\rvert+\lvert f\rvert-\lvert f_n-f\rvert)\, d\mu\\&=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(\int\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu+\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu-\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu\right)\\&=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu+\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu-\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n\rvert\, d\mu+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu-\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu\\&=2\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu-\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu\\&\Leftrightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu=0
\end{align}

It is not totally clear to me, why now it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu=0$.

Is it, because the sequence $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, g_n:=\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert\, d\mu$ is bounded below by $0$ and decreases monotonously, because $\lvert f_n-f\rvert\to 0$ almost surely, and therefore converges, what means it has exactly one limit point that then has to be the limsup, which is 0?

"$\Leftarrow$" is clear.

Comment: An easier proof is to observe that by the triangle inequality for any complex numbers $0 \leq |a - b| + |b| - |a| \leq 2|b|$.  If $|f|$ is integrable, the result follows immediately from dominated convergence.

Comment: Note that $\liminf (-\text{something})=-\limsup \text{something}$, not $-\liminf \text{something}$ (5th line of displayed equations). Hence you actually proved a stronger result than you believe.

Comment: @Did Then my proof is wrong from line 5? sHow can I correct it? Indeed, I was not sure how I can continue from line 4.

Comment: I edited it. Still I do not know, why now it follows that the Limes is 0.

Comment: You simply still need to realize that for any *nonnegative* sequence $(x_n)$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ are equivalent.

Comment: One last question. Why is the step from line 4 to line 5 okay, i.e. why is it okay to caclulate the liminf of the sum as the sum of the liminfs?